# Similar to Richie Hawtin's Consumed and Concept 1 albums

Tags: similar-artists

Richie Hawtin is a Canadian techno artist. He has a couple of albums that I always use to listen to whilst working. They are downtempo electronic with a lot of sound manipulation giving what I find to be a very atmospheric and 'cold' but highly focussed listening experience. I would love to find some similar albums. As far as I'm aware he didn't do anything else like Consumed and Concept 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anthony Rother has made similar albums.  One such album is "Geomatrix" which I had the joy of discovering as a hidden CD in his Telekraft album.  He has a few other albums like that.

If you want something a bit older, there is Laurie Spiegel's pioneering work from the 60s and 70s.